# Allow only numbers in React by onKeyPress or onKeyDown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onkeydown, onkeypress

I need the user to enter only numbers in the input field.
I tried by using onKeyPress & onKeyDown Events. I am unable to get the boolean values form the Events .Any help would be appreciated.

```
class User extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: ''}
    this.keyPress = this.keyPress.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
 }
  keyPress(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
       console.log('value', e.target.value);
       }
    else{
      const charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
        return false;
      }
      else{
         return true;
      }
    }
 }
<input
 type='text'
 value={this.state.value}
 onKeyDown={this.keyPress(event)}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use **input type="number"**. It doesn't allow any letters.

If you are going to use masks then you can try [this](https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask)

As you can see in the snippet you can restrict the mask for numbers with the char: 9 and even specify a char that sits between spaces.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ReactInputMask mask="999 999 999" maskChar="_" />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!-- Will be exported to window.ReactInputMask -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-mask/dist/react-input-mask.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I cannot use type= 'number' because I need to mask the input  later with Strings like "XXX".

Comment: Thank you so much ,my intention is to hide the numbers with  the string of XXX so that the user cannot see once the focus is out. Ex 1234 to XXXX

Answer (score 0):

Use input `type="number"`. It restricts the user to just writing numbers

Comment: Thank you!! I am afraid I  can't use type= 'number' because I need to mask the input later with Strings like "XXX".